# Running 3-4 red LEDs on 3xAAA batteries efficiently

Tags: led, led-strip

I have one of these generic Motion Sensor LED Night ([example](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002520461159.html)) and I modified it to stay on all night on a much dimmer light. It lasts about 150 hours the way it is now (I just disconnected the IR sensor and added another resistor to make it draw less current).

Now I'm thinking about modifying it to use red LEDs (because apparently white/blue light is not good for your sleep cycle at night).

I'm wondering if it's ok to plug 3 or 4 normal red LEDs (voltage drop ~1.8 V) instead of the SMD ones that come with this module. I don't really understand how they manage to plug 6 white LEDs from 3xAAA batteries (total ~3.6 V).

[image: IR motion led]

Comment: Propably they put 2 x 3 LEDs (or similar) in parallel and not all of them in series.

Comment: Alcaline battery voltage 1.5V. 1.2V is rechargeable Ni-Cd. White LED may be connected in parallel, with resistor for each.

Comment: I know for a fact that a similar light from Ikea has all white LEDs in parallel. Even if you connected 2 red LEDs in series and they would light up, the battery voltage would only have to drop a little and the LEDs will dim. I would use high-efficiency red LEDs and limit the current through them (to 5 mA for example) to make the batteries last longer.

Comment: I have a cheap flashlight with 24 white LEDs in parallel and powered from 3 AAA cells. Obviously the forward voltage of the LEDs are  matched and the cheap batteries that are half filled with rice are the current limiter. Using normal western made alkaline battery cells I needed to add one current-limiting resistor. Each LED in parallel does not need its own series resistor if the forward voltages of the LEDs are the same.